What's the best way to create an immutable extension of a class in Typescript?
If I have
class Person {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

and I want
class ImmutablePerson extends Person {
  readonly id: number;
  readonly name: string;
  constructor(i: number, n: string) {
    this.id = i;
    this.name = n;
  }
}

is there a more efficient (i.e. less redundant) way to achieve this?  It feels like there should be something similar to using Readonly<Person> but that of course only works on types, not classes.
(NOTE I'd be fine going the other way from ImmutablePerson to Person)

Not sure why Readonly<Person> doesn't work for you. Note that ImmutablePerson, as described here, is a dead class that cannot be used. You cannot create it and give it values. Because the properties are readonly. But if Person has a constructor that instantiates all, then something like makeImmutablePerson = (...args): Readonly<Person> => new Person(...args) is the easiest option.

Left the constructor out for brevity, but you're right (editing now).  As for your solution, it's elegant, but I was hoping for an actual extended class.  Perhaps I can make it work without...

I don't see how it makes sense to put this in the class hierarchy. Consider what happens if you have class Employee extends Person. How would you then have ImmutableEmployee in any sensible way?

Also true.  In this particular project, that won't happen, so I didn't consider it, but you are, again, right.

"Readonly<Person> of course only works on types, not classes" - the class does declare a type, Readonly<Person> works just fine! readonly modifiers are a type-only thing anyway, your ImmutablePerson is totally equivalent to Person at runtime. You'd have to Object.freeze it or something to make an actually difference, but then again, you can just freeze an ordinary Person.

• Is there a reason you're not initializing your Person class properly? new Person() will create something without required properties. If you use --strict (and you should) then you'll get errors just declaring uninitialized required fields. • If you fix that, do you actually want ImmutablePerson to just be Readonly at the type level? Or at runtime too? Are you Object.freeze()ing or not? • You could make a helper that Immutable-izes class constructors, like in this playground link, but I don't know if that's what you want. Please [edit] to clarify.

class Person {
  id: number;
  name: string;

  constructor(id: number, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class ImmutablePerson extends Person {
  constructor(id: number, name: string) {
    super(id, name);
    Object.freeze(this); // makes instance immutable
  }
}

Usage:
let immutablePerson = new ImmutablePerson(1, 'Joe');
console.log(immutablePerson.id); // Output: 1
console.log(immutablePerson.name); // Output: 'Joe'

// Attempting to modify properties will result in an error:
// immutablePerson.id = 2; // Error: Cannot assign to 'id' because it is a read-only property.


It doesn't affect the type. Only throws a runtime error, however, the whole point of TS is to prevent runtime errors by solving them at compile time.

@VLAZ in that case:
this is the way

Then Person is immutable, ImmutablePerson is not needed with that code.
